# jenkins : cppcheck not running

Tags: jenkins, cppcheck

I am trying to launch cppcheck for my `tepp` project under jenkins environment, system is win7-x64:

- I installed cppcheck.exe under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\cppcheck`
- Jenkins config, shell exec path is : `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`
- As documentation suggested, jenkins launches cppcheck analysis as following :

  - I add an "execute shell script" task
  - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\cppcheck\cppcheck.exe" -j 8 --enable=all --inconclusive --xml --xml-version=2 tepp 2> tepp/tepp-cppcheck.xml`

The ouput is :

```
[tepp] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe
C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3799822801570258901.sh
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits r‚serv‚s.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tepp>Finished: SUCCESS
```

No xml output file, nothing in logs, quiet failed.

When I execute this command line under a cmd windows, it works fine : bunch of logs, big xml file generated ...

Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

Cppcheck must be invoked via "windows batch" and not "execute shell script".

I thought "shell script" is interpreted via some bash/sh jenkins under linux and via cmd under windows. It isn't !

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tested the cppcheck plugin ? 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cppcheck+Plugin

My team created it .. and the cppcheck team is using it now.